# If each $A_n$ is a set of sequences of natural numbers, how is $A=\prod A_n$ to be viewed?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, infinite-product

I can see that $A$ is, by definition of the product, the set of sequences $(a_1,a_2,...)$ such that each $a_i$ is itself a sequence belonging to $A_i$.

I'm wondering is there another way of looking at this product, possibly involving commutativity of the cartesian product.

I am generalizing my question from a more specific question that is stumping me from a paper but it will be hard for me to give the exact specifics.

EDIT: I meant to mention, is there a way of viewing this product $A$ as a set of sequences of natural numbers?

Comment: It's not clear what kind of answer you looking for.  How would you say that $\sum A_n$ *"is to be viewed"*?

Comment: Do you mean instead that each $A_n$ is a **set** of natural numbers?  And again, I still think your question is too vague for me to know what you're actually after here

Comment: I think OP is talking about sequence of partial products.

Comment: Each set $A_n$ is a set of sequences.  An element in $A_n$ is a sequence of natural numbers.

Comment: @user41728 thanks for clarifying, that's not what your title says.

Comment: I have edited the title, I'm sorry.

Comment: There is no universally accepted meaning to what it means to multiply two sequences together.  So It's meaningless to talk of a product of sequences without defining how to multiply two sequences together first.  If you define that then... you question is obvious.  If you don't, your question is meaningless.  So how are you defining $A_1 \times A_2$?  If that is your question, then my answer is there is not universal answer.

Comment: Ah, you are taking of cartesian products .... well....

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you are talking cartesian products.  $\prod A_i = \{(a_1,a_2, ..., a_n)|a_i \in A_i\}$ which is a set of all possible $n$-tuples.

It's not a sequence itself but instead if $A_i$ is a sequence in some space $X_i$

$\prod A_i = A_1 \times.... \times A_n \subset X_1 \times ... \times X_n$.

If the sequences are all sequences from the same space $X$ (say, $\mathbb R$) then $\prod A_i \subset X^n$.

So if they are all sequences of real numbers, then $\prod A_i \subset \mathbb R^n$.